# Process running on top of node REPL

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to run a process on top of node REPL. The objective here is to allow users to use the node REPL the way they would by simply typing a command into their terminals, but to load some modules automatically into that REPL.

The solution to this problem would be best if somehow the stdin was piped back and forth to the REPL running in the background, but also satisfactory if the REPL simply had some modules loaded into it prior to allowing the user to inout stdin.

What I could do would be to work with `process.stdin.resume()` to allow users to input commands, evaluate them, and process them inside of the already running node process, but this is duplicating functionality of the already existing node REPL.

Is there any way to do this? Does `child_process` have a medium for this kind of control?

Any proposed solution can also use es6. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** Please let me know what I can do to improve this question as it has been viewed several times, but not touched. I cannot provide an example because I do not know how I would go about doing something like this.

Comment: Regarding your edit: Maybe it is just me, but I think you may get more traction with this question if you tried to explain or describe what you want to do rather than basically describing a "how". When you say "node shell" do you mean the node REPL at the command line? Are you talking about nwjs? Is the idea a user can type a command into the REPL that will execute a long running task, and you want to return the user to the REPL, have the long-running task run in a separate process, presumably emitting its output to the console when it has finished?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this? It might inform an answer.

Comment: Also, could you clarify what you mean by "node shell"? Are you referring to  https://github.com/wdavidw/node-shell? Or the REPL? Or something else? It would help a lot if you carefully chose your terminology and defined terms that would be unfamiliar to people (like "node shell").

Comment: @Trott I don't think the terminology shell is that outlandish. REPL is better, but pretty much any language introspective tool that runs in the terminal is a shell. ie: Python Shell, Ruby Shell?

Comment: @barry-johnson Your comment is not very helpful, my apologies. I've already done my best to describe what I want to do. I haven't made any reference to a package of any sort.

Comment: @BTC It is true that "shell" is not an outlandish choice in terminology. I asked because I started going down the REPL path to come up with an answer and then thought, "But what if they're talking about some module or some other thing I've never heard of?" Sorry if I came off as condescending rather than welcoming and/or inquisitive.

Comment: @Trott Ah! You would have had it!! Thanks for the feedback all the same!

Comment: As long as you got the help you needed and there's a good answer here for someone else who is looking for the same thing, then everyone gets a high five.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen the built in repl module?

https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html

It looks like it covers everything you want to do.

If you want a custom context, you would probably need to pass a custom `eval` function. The node documentation has examples.

Comment: Yep, it's all there. Sometimes it's just a matter of pointing someone in the right direction. Worst...bounty...ever. Thanks!